# Android How to get image URL from recyclerView (Not Local image)

Tags: android, android-intent, android-recyclerview, retrofit2, android-glide

My Problem is that I have a recyclerView consists of list of images (From Flickr_API)  and their text , What I want to do is When the user tap on any photo a new RecyclerView should be showed listing more photos for that particular user. So , I'm trying to catch the image url once the user clicks on it (any other solution solve the problem will be Accepted)
I've tried to set a clickListner Function on my BindViewHolder in my RecyclerView Adapter Class like this :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final FlickrPhoto photo = photos.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(photo.title);
    uri = Uri.parse(photo.image);
    Glide.with(context).load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).crossFade().into(holder.imageView);
   PhotoViewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,SpecificUserPhotoRecyclerView.class);
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });
```

My Connection service is Retrofit2 and I am using Glide Library to catch images from Flickr_API .
So , please help me How do I pass any data helps me for catching more user photos in the other class (Which my Intent refers to ) .

**Note**
My photos that I'm trying to catch along all my project isn't local images 
because, I found many solutions but all depends on your drawable folder which will not help me in my case .

**Edit**
After trying to use SetTag and getTag in my onBindViewHolder Like this :

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(final PhotoViewHolder holder, final int position) {
    final FlickrPhoto photo = photos.get(position);
    holder.textView.setText(photo.title);
    uri = Uri.parse(photo.image);
    Glide.with(context).load(uri).placeholder(R.drawable.image_placeholder).crossFade().into(holder.imageView);

   PhotoViewHolder.imageView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            holder.imageView.setTag(photo.title);
            Context context = v.getContext();
            Intent intent = new Intent(context,SpecificUserPhotoRecyclerView.class);
            intent.putExtra("title",String.valueOf(holder.imageView.getTag()).toString());
            intent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK);
            Toast.makeText(context,holder.imageView.getTag().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            context.startActivity(intent);

        }
    });


}
```

I've Got a correct Toast message with the correct imgTitle but when I've tried to receive that Intent on the other class I receive it with null value

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_specific_user_photo);
    //photosListActivity = new PhotosListActivity();
    RecyclerView recyclerView = (RecyclerView) findViewById(R.id.user_photo_recycler_view);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(new GridLayoutManager(getApplicationContext(),1));
    adapter = new PhotosRecyclerViewAdapter(getApplicationContext(),getPhotos());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(adapter);
     Intent intent = new Intent();
    String titleImg = intent.getStringExtra("title");
    Log.w("============>imgURL = "+titleImg,"***********");
    Toast.makeText(this,titleImg,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you can set imageUrl as setTag with ImageView,

```
holder.imageView.setTag(photo.title);
```

And when user click it,

you can get the value,

```
holder.imageView.getTag();
```

Hope this will help you.

Thanks,

Comment: I have added this `holder.imageView.setTag(photo.title);` in my onBindViewHolder function and then in the onClickListner I have added this `holder.imageView.getTag();` but I want to make sure that is works , so I tried to solutions 
First one , `Toast.makeText(context,holder.imageView.getTag().toString(),Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show()` but it doesn't shown anything

Comment: The Second is , `intent.putExtra("title",holder.imageView.getTag().toString());` and go to my second class to receive that intent like this `Intent intent = new Intent();
String titleImg = intent.getStringExtra("title");
Log.w("============>imgURL = ",titleImg+"***********");`  
but it is also not works

Comment: What you are getting in the toast, any value or null? When you get your result with getTag() you need to pass in the intent given above.

Comment: Toast didn't shown anything and my Log also doesn't show anything , any message doesn't appear !! Which is strange for me ! 

So , you mean that the intent is correct solution but after we make sure that the setTag and getTag works well ?

Comment: After restarting my android studio and run my app again  , the main recyclerView doesn't appear and app stopped working with this error message at my Logcat `java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: You must not call setTag() on a view Glide is targeting`

Comment: Now , I've moved both `holder.imageView.setTag(photo.title);` and `holder.imageView.getTag();` to the onClickListner and the toast shows a correct photo title , but When I send data to Intent and Receive it in the other activity it shown null on my Logcat
@Silvans Solanki

Comment: Can you please update your code in your question, so i will get better idea. Thanks

Comment: I've added an Edit part on my original question  , Kindly check it .

Comment: Looks like I've made a stupid mistake . 
In the other class I've added Intent = new Intent Instead of Inent.getIntent() , I'm sorry about that 
and Thank u very much for ur help and ur time :) 
@Silvans Solanki